# Does smtp4dev support displaying HTML element?

Tags: php, email, smtp4dev

A while ago I downloaded **smtp4dev** so I can listen to emails from **port 25**, I'm programming with **PHP** and when I send an **PHP** script, **smtp4dev** displays the email, but what If I want to check if it displays **HTML** elements such as `(p) (img) (hr)`, etc...

If it's not possible please guide me to some alternatives that can give me this feature.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to send email with html content from Php. You can use a Php package called [Mail](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail) or you can use the inbuilt function [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)